# pandas data frame from list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples that I want to convert to pandas data frame and write to excel with column headers.

```
Column_headers = ["Name", "Count1", "Count2"]

mylist = [('A',(1,2)), ('B',(23,2)), ('C',(1,23)), ('D',(5,23))]
```

Output in Excel

```
Name | Count1 | Count2
A    | 1      | 2
B    | 23     | 2
C    | 1      | 23
D    | 5      | 23
```

I tried below but it only saves the last entry in mylist.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

start_row = 0
for i, data in enumerate(mylist):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": [data[0]],
                   "Count1": [data[1][0]],
                   "Count2": [data[1][1]]})

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',header=True, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Can someone please provide any pointers?

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
Column_headers = ["Name", "Count1", "Count2"]
mylist = [('A',(1,2)), ('B',(23,2)), ('C',(1,23)), ('D',(5,23))]
df = pd.DataFrame([[i[0], i[1][0], i[1][1]] for i in mylist], columns=Column_headers)
df.to_excel('demo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I had to do - df.to_excel(writer) to save the output in Excel. The data frame printed out exactly how I wanted.

Comment: @omz My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` here

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(map(chain.from_iterable, mylist), columns=Column_headers)

  Name  Count1  Count2
0    A       1       2
1    B      23       2
2    C       1      23
3    D       5      23
```